BigQuery API: Create table out of google sheets
I have a spreadsheet created manually with some data inside. In the bigquery console, I can do:
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE \`PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE\`
OPTIONS (
  format = 'GOOGLE_SHEETS',
  uris = ['https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID']
);

and that creates me a table with the data from the spreadsheet just fine. However, when I attempt the same thing using the big query API:
BQ_QUERY=$(cat <<EOF
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE \`PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE\`
OPTIONS (
  format = 'GOOGLE_SHEETS',
  uris = ['https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID']
);
EOF
)

curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token --account=MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{\"query\": \"$BQ_QUERY\", \"useLegacySql\": false}" \
"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT/queries" | jq


I get:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "accessDenied"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

why is that?

looks like I needed this before the call:
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly 


Yes, this is clearly a permission issue. The error message "Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials." means that the BigQuery service account used for your API request doesn't have the necessary permissions to access the Google Sheet you're referencing. Also, verify if the BigQuery service account is added as "Editor" to your Google sheet.
